# Order of integration for a double integral

Tags: integration

This seems like it should be a very simple question but it's been a while since learning calculus and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Basically, when I have a double integral $$\int_{0}^{z}\int_0^1dxdy$$, it clearly evaluates to z. If I reverse the order of integration:

$$\int_0^1\int_{0}^{z}dydx$$
then it evaluates to 1/2. This doesn't seem to make any sense and I suspect it's the boundaries are somehow wrong when I reversed the order of integration. But what is the right boundary then?

Comment: It is a reasonable idea to worry about, whether interchanging the order of integration will result in the same answer.  But what you've written is not an apt expression of this concern.  Please fill in the details, as I imagine you've made a subtle error in doing the second integral.  Variable $z$ is not related to $x$ or $y$ in what you wrote, so there's no way for it to disappear when the integration happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually,$$\int_0^1\int_0^z\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1z\,\mathrm dx=z.$$